# export returns empty when I use gridview in loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
  foreach (ListItem item in ckblTables.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                grvExport.DataSource = null;
                grvExport.DataSource = Data.Select("select * from "+item.Text+"");
                grvExport.DataBind();
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), item.Text, "table = new Tabulator('#grvExport'); table.download('csv', 'table.csv'); ", true);
            }
        }
```

> If I use two grids and do this export two times this goes well on a
>   button click but when I loop it, I only get the last table exported
>   and other excels are exported too but they are empty.

Comment: I think you shall use different name for csv file in each loop

Comment: I used even that but all sheets are empty apart from last one.